# Can't delete selected item, only delete last item added in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete data based on company_id and year from my database.
[image]

sample data content

[image]

my route in web.php

```
    Route::post('delete_master_cuti/{company_id}/{year}', [CompanyMasterCutiController::class, 'delete_master_cuti'])->name('delete_master_cuti');
```

my model in App\Models, I've added the company_id and year to be for the primary key

```
class CompanyMasterCuti extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'company_master_cuti';
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'year', 'cuti', 'created', 'created_by', 'modified', 'modified_by', 
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = ['company_id', 'year'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

my code in controller. when I return the results of the $master_cuti data I get the last data I entered, not the data I selected

```
 public function delete_master_cuti(Request $request) {

        $master_cuti = CompanyMasterCuti::where($request->company_id)->where($request->year);
        $master_cuti->delete();

        toast('Successfull', 'success');
        return redirect()->route('master-cuti.index');

    }
```

in index.blade.php I have defined the data to be deleted based on the selected company_id and year

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#company_id','#year').val($(this).data(['company_id','year'])); $('#deleteModalBu').modal('show');">                                                            
       <i class="badge-circle badge-circle-light-secondary bx bxs-trash font-medium-1 text-danger my-1"></i>
</a>
```

form delete modal

```
 <form id="form-edit" action="{{ route('delete_master_cuti', [$m_cuti->company_id, $m_cuti->year] ) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" id="company_id" name="company_id">
                            <input type="hidden" id="year" name="year">

                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        style="width: 100%;">
                                        <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">CANCEL</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ml-1" style="width: 100%">
                                        <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">DELETE</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
       </form>
```

I want to delete data based on the company_id and year I chose, but why is the deleted data the last time I entered? how to solve my problem? anyone, help me.

Answer (score 0):

you must specify the column name (company_id and year) in the query. for example :

```
public function delete_master_cuti(Request $request) {

    $request->validate([
        'company_id' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required'
    ]);

    $master_cuti = CompanyMasterCuti::where('company_id',$request->company_id)->where('year', $request->year);
    $master_cuti->delete();

    toast('Successfull', 'success');
    return redirect()->route('master-cuti.index');

}
```

and add softDelete in your model and add deleted_at column in your database table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class CompanyMasterCuti extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDelte;
    ...
}
```

and you can add the code in your blade file for show validation error

```
    @if(count($errors) > 0)

    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: if I use the $request variable the data becomes null which will be deleted

Comment: the best practice, you use check validation and use softDelete and the data inside $request variable should not be null

Comment: sorry i mean like what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the response from "public function delete_master_cuti(Request $request)" by return $request->all(), whether company_id & year in method?

Comment: I checked and company_id and year is null

Comment: Try to use variable in input value?  <input type="hidden" id="company_id" name="company_id" value="{{$m_cuti->company_id}}">
<input type="hidden" id="year" name="year" value="{{$m_cuti->year}}">

Comment: I have added values to the input but the deleted data is still the data I entered last